# Complex SQL transformation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my source table

```
Reference   ModifiedDate
------------------------------------
1023175     2017-03-03 16:02:01.723
1023175     2017-03-07 07:59:49.283
1023175     2017-03-12 11:14:40.230
```

Ineed the following output

```
Reference   StartDate                 EndDate
---------------------------------------------
1023175   2017-03-03 16:02:01.723     2017-03-07 07:59:49.283
1023175   2017-03-07 07:59:49.283     2017-03-12 11:14:40.230
1023175   2017-03-12 11:14:40.230     9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 (last record should have this value)
```

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Don't tag products not involved. Put one the tags back, the one for the dbms you're using.

Comment: May I suggest a left join from source on source?

Comment: Also, a specific version tag would probably help

Comment: Are you really looking for a solution that would work for 3 different database products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (Reference INT, ModifiedDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES

(1023175, '2017-03-03 16:02:01.723'),
(1023175, '2017-03-07 07:59:49.283'),
(1023175, '2017-03-12 11:14:40.230');

SELECT
    T1.Reference, 
    T1. ModifiedDate AS Start_Date, 
    COALESCE(MIN(T2.ModifiedDate),CAST('31/12/9999' AS DATETIME))  as EndDate
FROM @MyTable T1
    LEFT JOIN @MyTable T2
ON T1.reference = T2.reference AND T1.ModifiedDate < T2.ModifiedDate 
GROUP BY 
    T1.Reference, 
    T1. ModifiedDate
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use lead/lag windowing function. It works from SQL Server2012 onwards... Before that you need to do self join with genereated row_number

```
select Reference, ModifiedDate as StartDate, 
    lead(ModifiedDate, 1, '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000') over(order by Reference) as EndDate
    from #yourreference
```

Table details

```
create table #yourreference (Reference int, ModifiedDate datetime)

insert into #yourreference (
Reference ,  ModifiedDate ) values
 (1023175   ,'2017-03-03 16:02:01.723')
,(1023175   ,'2017-03-07 07:59:49.283')
,(1023175   ,'2017-03-12 11:14:40.230')
```

Comment: Not on all database products. Sql server only started supporting lag and lead in 2012 version. I don't know about Oracle or Sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select a.Reference, a.ModifiedDate as StartDate, 
        coalesce(min(b.ModifiedDate),9999-12-31 00:00:00.000)  as EndDate
 from source_table as a
 left join source_table as b
 on a.reference = b.reference and a.ModifiedDate < b.ModifiedDate 
 group by a.Reference, a.ModifiedDate
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in Oracle versions from 9i:

```
select reference
       , modifieddate as startdate
       , lead ( modifieddate, 1, to_timestamp('9999-12-31 00:00:00.000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3'))
                 over (partition by reference order by modifieddate) as enddate
from your_table;
```

Note that the windowing clause needs to sort by `modifieddate` to ensure the correct value.